# Azure database connection limit

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Could you please tell me whether or not is there any connection limit in same time towards database? I read on different forums different suggestion but it looks like there is 180 max connection in same time possible is that true?

Additional question: i have created sql database basic with 2 gb size and 5 UDS - can anyone tell me is this fix price for it or it depends on database utilization - would appreciate any information on that as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the basic, then your concurrent connections are [limited to 30](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/) - 
[image]

You [pay for what you use](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/sql-database/), the monthly estimate shown is based on 744 hours per month.

Comment: "what i use" so if i choose this basic with 5DTU so from my understanding and from calculator i see for my basic database 2 gb plan is 1x744 = 4,20Euro so this is static price every month, or they also adding some extra for that for database workload (cpu,memory)? Can you please explain for newbie?

Comment: I believe the overall costing is a combination of database size, and how much data is transferred in/out of the cloud.  cpu/memory are more down to the choice of basic, standard, premium, etc. which have a higher price point.

Comment: so why static price for this partirural plan 4,20 e/month :O

Comment: The static price is for the Azure SQL service. The [Network Data transfer service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/) is different, it measures the Outbound data the goes out of Azure datacenters. The first 5Gb are free, then you have to pay, it's not really a lot, but you might see a few cents or dollars depending on how much bandwidth is consumed.

Comment: is it always 5 gb or? And could you explain easy way what is this DTU from msdn hard to udnerstand.